# CSS Transition font-size: avoid jittering / wiggling

Tags: html, css

I made the following tile, with an hover-effect that increases the `font-size` with an CSS-`transition`:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
}
.website {
  width: 180px;
  height: 73px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin: 1px;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 5px solid darkslateblue;
  background-color: darkslateblue;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: border-color 0.66s ease-out, font-size 0.3s ease-out;
}
.website:hover {
  font-size: 16pt;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: border-color 0s;
  border-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="website">Blog 1</div>
<div class="website">Blog 2</div>
<div class="website">Blog 3</div>
```

When you hover them you can see that the transition of the `font-size` is not smooth at all. In other words it wiggles up and down when changing size.
Does anyone have an Idea  how to fix or work around it?

Comment: The wiggling is because the font size is scaled in whole points, so the size animation isn't as smooth as you want it to be.

Comment: This is actually the correct answer, browsers manipulate the positioning of fonts so they look optimal. If you slow down the animation to five seconds or so you'll see the characters jump as the browser interpolates them. The accepted answer is a workaround.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use CSS `transform:scale` instead for a smoother transition like so:

```
.website:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: border-color 0.4s;
  border-color: black;
}
.website div {
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
}
.website:hover div {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transition: transform 0s;
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hrzjebhn/)

Also note that I added the texts within a `div` and the scaling was done on the `div` so that the *whole* box is not scaled :)

Comment: That is a (the) solution. Note though, that `transform:scale` tends to have a pit of blurry/pixely result when zooming in. You may consider experimenting with having a larger font that is scaled down by default and scaled up to its normal size when hovering.

Comment: I just had the same Idea, it's working great (also I'd prefer not to add an extra element), and the Browser seems to get rid of the blurryneess when not animating. However I can't get it to work so it pops in on max size right when I hover, and zooms back when I leave the Element.

Answer (score 4):

On hover put  `transition: border-color 0s, font-size 0.3s ease-out;`

Because on hover `transition: border-color 0s` will give only `border-color` transition not give to `font-size`.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
}
.website {
  width: 180px;
  height: 73px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin: 1px;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 5px solid darkslateblue;
  background-color: darkslateblue;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: border-color 0.66s ease-out, font-size 0.3s ease-out;
}
.website:hover {
  font-size: 16pt;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: border-color 0s, font-size 0.3s ease-out;
  border-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="website">Blog 1</div>
<div class="website">Blog 2</div>
<div class="website">Blog 3</div>
```

Comment: sorry, that was not the problem. It was my intention to make it pop on entering the hover. The problem is that the text wiggles up and down when changing size

Answer (score 0):

Initially, I was using `font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;`
It had shaky like earthquake animation. (Some test in divs were smooth, some were not. Inconsistent and random). Later, I did some change.

```
`@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap');

body {
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}`
```

now, animations (especially font size animations) are smooth.
Either the jittering animation is the problem of font specific. or the font you want to use failed to load in your browser.