# Text is shaking on increasing font size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to increase font-size on click-through jquery by adding class but facing a very strange issue. The text starts shaking while it is getting bigger. Can anybody give me a solution and explain to me why it is happening? Actually, I have tried scale and my text is not shaking on transform: scale but I don't want scale there. It should work out through font-size.

The gif quality is not smooth, but as you can see it is shaking up and down.

[image]

Here is the working example of code.

```js
$("div h3").click(function() {
 $("div h3").removeClass("active");
 $(this).addClass("active");
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
div {
  
}
div h3 {
  font-size:40px;
  font-weight:800;
  opacity:0.3;
  margin:0;
  transition:0.4s ease all;
}
div h3.active {
  font-size:60px;
  opacity:1;
  transition:0.4s ease all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div>
  <h3>Hello</h3>
  <h3>Hello</h3>
  <h3>Hello</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: now that you pointed out this example, I can see a lot of things shaking on my screen.

Comment: I would guess it might have something to do with the size change. Could you try changing 

  font-size:60px;

To:

font-size:40px;

And let me know if it still happens?

Comment: @ZacharyMcGee Sure, let me check real quick.

Comment: does it still happen if you try `transform: scale(1.5)` instead of font size change?

Comment: The default font size is 40px, if I change the active font size from 60px to 40px, then it will do nothing. i mean the font -size will stay static! isn't?

Comment: @GamersAgenda exactly, this will help you diagnose where the root of the problem is. I first wanted to make sure that it was the font size change causing it, then we could go from there.

Comment: @Clarity Actually it works fine on a scale, it didn't shake but scale zoom in text from the center. but my text is already aligned left. if it gets zoomed in, it will go out from screen! so it will not work as expected. if you have idea solving it through scaling, let me know, please.

Comment: it is font-size issue i guess. or maybe font-family issue, I don't really know. but i guess is it font-size

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45078000/jquery-animate-fontsize-back-to-original-size-on-click, I see these shake issues in all the `font-size` examples. You can use a different approach like scale or height(I'm not sure about this, still checking)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use scale and adjust the transform-origin:

```js
$("div h3").click(function() {
 $("div h3").removeClass("active");
 $(this).addClass("active");
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
div {
  overflow:hidden;
}
div h3 {
  font-size:40px;
  font-weight:800;
  opacity:0.3;
  margin:0;
  transition:0.4s ease all;
  transform-origin:left;
}
div h3.active {
  transform:scale(1.5);
  opacity:1;
  transition:0.4s ease all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div>
  <h3>Hello</h3>
  <h3>Hello</h3>
  <h3>Hello</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Yeah, it will work too but why the font-size making an issue?  You have any idea?

Comment: @GamersAgenda from this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34717492/css-transition-font-size-avoid-jittering-wiggling/34717782

"The wiggling is because the font size is scaled in whole points, so the size animation isn't as smooth as you want it to be."

Comment: @GamersAgenda because the interpolation of font-size is a more difficult task for the browser than scaling a whole element. changing font-size affect the rendring of each character and it will also affect the line box while the scale will consdier the whole element

Comment: I appreciate your help, I have a question about font-families, are they cause shaking issues?

Comment: I had an example site where the developer achieves the same thing but his content is not shaking. [here](https://www.stakeunion.com/#tech) I don't know third party links allowed there or not. But on the other hand, I had a site [link](https://elitepropertydesign.co.uk/stakeUnion/#Tech). I didn't really figure out the problem.

Comment: @GamersAgenda it's random, there is a lot of factor in play (font-family, font-size, line-height, etc) so you may find a combination without shacking but it's not something you can easily find. It depend on how the browser will do the calculation. Don't forget that the transition is also an important factor, a different duration or easing may also remove the shacking

Comment: Yeah, thankyou so much. I think i am ready to mark this answer. And good luck to your 100K :)